# How to get PDF box size from CGPDFPage

Tags: swift, macos, cgpdf

I'm getting errors however I try to get the mediabox of a PDF Page in Swift.:

```
if let pdf = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL) {
    let numberOfPages = pdf.numberOfPages
    for index in 0...numberOfPages {
        let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: index)
        print(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage!, kCGPDFMediaBox))

}
```

I've also tried:

```
print(pdfPage.getBoxRect(kCGPDFMediaBox))
```

as well as using `PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox`, `mediaBox` and pretty much every other variant. It works fine in python.
I can also get the info fine using `PDFPage` (as opposed to `CGPDFPage`), but I need to use `CGPDFPage` for other things that `PDFPage` can't do.)

The second part is: from what I can tell, the mediaBox result does not factor in the rotation. So a landscape page might have a portrait mediabox with a rotation of 90. Is there any easy way to get the "actual" display dimensions, or do I have to do the transformation myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF pages are numbered starting at `1`, not at zero. And `getBoxRect()`
takes a `enum CGPDFBox` argument in Swift 3. So this should work:

```
for pageNo in 1...pdf.numberOfPages {
    if let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: pageNo) {
        let mediaBox = pdfPage.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        print(mediaBox)
    }
}
```

The PDF bounding boxes do not take the page rotation into account.
The following might work to compute the rotated box (untested):

```
// Get rotation angle and convert from degrees to radians:
let angle = CGFloat(pdfPage.rotationAngle) * CGFloat.pi / 180
// Apply rotation transform to media box:
let rotatedBox = mediaBox.applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle))
```

Comment: rotatedBox is a CGRect, but I need CGPDFBox object to pass in myCGPDFpage.getBoxRect method. Error message says: cannot convert value of type 'CGRect' to specified type 'CGPDFBox'. Please help. I am using Swift 3. Thanks.

Comment: @appFormation: I am not sure if I understand your question. `CGPDFBox` is an enumeration and specifies *which* box you want to retrieve in `getBoxRext()` (mediabox, clip box, artbox, ...). The above code passes `.media`, you can replace that with your value.